# Why collection<object> is not the super type of all Collections?

Tags: java, generics

I`m currently trying to study java generics and I`m trying to understand wilcards .
I was reading java docs and I encountered this information below. Can you please clarify why
Collection is not the supertype of all collections and it is when we use Collection<?>  ?
Is this because , in example , we can pass a collection into a collection ?

thank you .
The text from docs is below :

Consider the problem of writing a routine that prints out all the elements in a collection. Here's how you might write it in an older version of the language (that is, a pre-5.0 release):

```
void printCollection(Collection c) {
Iterator i = c.iterator();
for (k = 0; k < c.size(); k++) {
    System.out.println(i.next());
}
```

}
And here is a naive attempt at writing it using generics (and the new for loop syntax):

```
     void printCollection(Collection<Object> c) {
      for (Object e : c) {
      System.out.println(e);
      }
        }
```

The problem is that this new version is much less useful than the old one. Whereas the old code could be called with any kind of collection as a parameter, the new code only takes Collection, which, as we've just demonstrated, is not a supertype of all kinds of collections!

So what is the supertype of all kinds of collections? It's written Collection<?> (pronounced "collection of unknown"), that is, a collection whose element type matches anything. It's called a wildcard type for obvious reasons. We can write:

```
    void printCollection(Collection<?> c) {
     for (Object e : c) {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Collection<Object>` says it is a collection of Objects, a `Collection<Integer>` is a collection of Integers, which are also Objects. You can add `String` to `Collection<Object>` but not to `Collection<Integer>` Hence, if you want to refer to the fact the Integer are Objects you can say, I have a `Collection<? extends Object>` That way you know `?` is more specific than `Object` but you only need to know they're Objects. eg. You cannot add a String to it.

Comment: You can *add* any kind of object into a `Collection<Object>`, but you can only add integers to `Collection<Integer>`, so clearly `Collection<Object>` is not a supertype of `Collection<Integer>`. Now try adding things to `Collection<?>` :)